# Spring Boot : Describe Applicaiton Context Graphically or Text Listing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot is great, but eventually we need to start customizing components in the assembly.

Is there a supported way to describe either graphically or a text listing all of the definitions that have been created automatically?

For example, currently I'd like to create a Spring Security authentication based on an HTTP header (api access token), and restrict access to REST endpoints to authenticated users.

If there is not a supported way, then I guess I'll just created an ApplicationContext aware bean and get it to dump the registry.

Also, am I missing something? How does one know how to customize a Spring Boot application assembly without knowing what is currently there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Actuator [endpoints](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints).
The beans endpoint will give you a json of all beans.

Also take a look at Spring Tool Suite's [Live Beans Graph](http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v310/NewAndNoteworthy.html)

Also a very good article [here](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/009-spring-boot-what-autoconfigurations-turned-on/).

Comment: Thank you @Evgeni. Do you know if IntelliJ also has something similar?

Comment: @JasperBlues Not sure. I don't use Intellij, sorry.